# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-1}{\tan x}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'd like help finding

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-1}{\tan x}$$

without the use of L'Hôpital's rule.

So far I did this:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-1}{\tan x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x(e^{2x}-1)}{\sin x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x\cos x(e^{2x}-1)}{x\sin x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x(e^{2x}-1)}{x}$$

Basically I got nowhere. Any hints or partial solutions to help me?

By the way, the is the 1969 AP BC Multiple Choice #28.

Comment: You can use that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{x}=2e^{2\times0}=2$$

Comment: Use Taylor expansion

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How does that work?

Comment: @LiLi I haven't learned this yet. Is that a good way to do these problems in general?

Comment: @MaxLi It's the derivative of $e^{2x}$ in $x=0$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is $C^n$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$(In fact, this condition can be reduced to $f'(x_0),f''(x_0),\cdots,f^{(n)}(x_0)$ exists) then $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}+o((x-x_0)^n)$

Comment: If you are studying in the course of calculus, I believe you will learn this theorem soon. In my own view,Taylor expansion is more essential than other estimates or L'Hospital Rule

Answer (score 3):

One may write, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\frac{e^{2x}-1}{\tan x}=2\cdot\frac{e^{2x}-1}{2x}\cdot \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \cos x
$$ then recognize standard limits.

Comment: What do I do after cancelling the sine with $x$ and cosine goes to 1; I get stuck after that.

Comment: @MaxLi, we know that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}{\sin x \over x} = 1$. Thus, it follows that $$\lim_{x\to0}{x \over \sin x} = \lim_{x\to0}{1\over {\sin x \over x}} = {\lim_{x\to0}(1)\over\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x \over x}} = {1 \over 1} = 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e^{2x} = 1 + 2x + o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$ and $\tan x = x + o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$. Hence,

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{\tan x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{[1+2x+o(x^2)]-1}{x+o(x^3)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x}{x} = 2.
$$

Comment: Where do you get the information in the first line of your answer?

Comment: @MaxLi Expand $e^{2x}$ and $\tan x$ in a Taylor series and just keep the first couple of terms.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^{2x}-1 = 2x (1+o(1))$ where $o(1)$ denotes a term going to $0$ as $x \to 0$ (see this from the maclaurin series of $e^{2x}$).

Then, you can write the thing you're taking the limit of as $\frac{2x}{\tan x} = \frac{2 x}{\sin x} \cos x$. You know $\frac{x}{\sin x} \to 1 $ as $x \to 0$ and $\cos x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where the logic for most of the answers comes from, and how we avoid the use L'Hopital's Rule.

First, let's observe a very important limit, namely $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}{e^h-1\over h}$. We know that $$e = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over x}\right)^{x} = \lim_{y\to0}\left(1 + y\right)^{1/y}.$$ So, using some creative algebra we have $$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}{e^h - 1 \over h} &= \lim_{y\to0}{y\over\ln(y+1)} \tag{Let $y = e^h - 1 \iff h = \ln(y+1)$}\\ &=\lim_{y\to0}\left({1\over{1\over y}\ln(y+1)}\right) \\ &=\lim_{y\to0}{1\over\ln[(1+y)^{1/y}]}\\&={1\over\ln(e)}\\&={1\over1} \\&= 1.\end{align}$$ Notice how the limit changes from $h\to0$ to $y\to0$ because as $x\to 0$, $y = e^h - 1 \to e^0 - 1 = 1-1=0$, hence $y\to 0$. Now, we begin the important part of proving the limit.

Using this result, it is very easy to prove that $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}{e^{2x} - 1\over x} &= \lim_{x\to0}\left({2\over2}\right)\left({e^{2x}-1\over x}\right)\\&=2\lim_{x\to0}{e^{2x}-1\over2x}\\&=2(1)\\&=2.\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have that $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}{e^{2x}-1\over\tan x} &=\lim_{x\to0}[(e^{2x} - 1)\cot(x)] \\ &=\lim_{x\to0}\left((e^{2x}-1)\cdot{\cos(x)\over \sin(x)}\right) \\ &=\lim_{x\to0}\left((e^{2x}-1)\cdot{2x\over2x}\cdot{\cos(x)\over \sin(x)}\right)\\&=2\lim_{x\to0}\left[{e^{2x}-1\over2x}\cdot{x\over\sin(x)}\cdot\cos(x)\right]\\&= 2\lim_{x\to0}\left[{e^{2x}-1\over2x}\cdot{1\over{\sin(x)\over x}}\cdot\cos(x)\right]\\&=2\left(1\cdot{1\over1}\cdot1\right)\\&=2.\end{align}$$